# XPath to return a list of all unique elements in tree that contain a string value

Tags: xpath, lxml

I'm trying to devise some XPath that will get me a list of every element in my tree that contains some string value (any value, as long as it's not empty), without duplicates. If I could return a list object, I could easily remove duplicates from it. I'm trying to serialize some XML to CSV and this is the best way I can think of to build out the header row...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 solution :

```
name((//*)[i][text()[normalize-space()]]
```

where `i` is the value to increment.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <year>Giada De Laurentis</year>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>euros</price>
</book>
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>euros</price>
  <colorcover>red</colorcover>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

R code :

```
a=list()
i=1
for (j in 1:xpathSApply(p,"count(//*)")) {
  xpath=paste0('name((//*)[',i,'][text()[normalize-space()]])')  
  a[[i]]=xpathSApply(p,xpath)
  i=i+1}
a=unlist(unique(a[-which(a=="")]))
```

Output :

```
"title"      "year"       "price"      "author"     "colorcover"
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to lean on Python and avoid the XPath as much as possible, this worked a treat:

```
columns = list(set([x.tag for x in root.iter() if x.text is not None]))
```